# Can nou use MUI without @emotion/react and @emotion/styled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If i try to install MUI in my react js aplication using `npm install @mui/material`, i get some errors:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/CSSTransition.js 5:0-47

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dom-helpers/addClass' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\app\node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\esm'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/CSSTransition.js 6:0-53

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dom-helpers/removeClass' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\app\node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\esm'
...
```

Why i can not use MUI without these additional libraries?

Comment: Take a look at `@mui/base` if you don't want the material-UI styling. It's still in beta, though.

Answer (score 0):

From the MUI [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) they use Emotion as its default styling engine. If you want you can configure as default styling engine `styled-components`, but i think is not possible to use it without `emotion` or `styled-components`